# replace words of a string maintain lowercase and uppercase chars

Tags: php, css

I have, for example, this string

```
$string='hello world, user admin';
```

how to echo `$string` as

```
**Hello World, User Admin.**
```

please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below function to display:

```
echo ucwords($string);
```

if you wish to change value of it to new uppercase (for 1st letter of word), use below:

```
 $string = ucwords($string);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

Comment: you mean echo ucwords($string)??

Comment: @I'mRajnikant yes, just edited for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

### Ucwords

```
$string='hello world, user admin';
echo ucwords($string);
```

[See Refrence here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `ucwords`

```
$string = 'hello world, user admin';
$uc_string = ucwords($string);
echo $uc_string;
```